# non-shell command running inside shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to run a non shell script command inside a `.sh` script.
Current code looks like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter name of the folder you want to join!"
read folder
cd ~/domains/name/public_html/$folder/sites/default/
echo "enabling u7seven theme!"
drush en u7seven -y;
echo "disabling overlay!"
drush dis overlay -y;
echo "running all-folder script!"
u7d7up all-folder
```

Code that is not a shell code(which is local script somewhere on the server is ):

`u7d7up all-folder`

However, if I go and manually call this function`u7d7up all-folder` from site root it works.
Since I am having more than 10 sites, i'd like to just call the script without entering and doing all these commands manually.

Comment: if it's in $PATH, and executable you should be able to just call it.  otherwise use absolute path or cd to the path it resides in.  otherwise this should work.  you may want to do something like var=\`u7d7up all-folder\` to get stdout to a variable and evaluate on $? to check the exit signal of the command.

Comment: Do you have a question?  Does running that command not work from a shell script?  If not can you please post the error you get?

Comment: check if $PATH holds the folder which contains 'u7d7up'

Comment: @Michael What are the outputs of `echo $PATH` and `type u7d7up`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be facing an issue due to non-presence of `u7d7up` in the $PATH variable.

A robust way to write your script will be put the absolute path of the `u7d7up`; also you would need to check for the permissions on it.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter name of the folder you want to join!"
read folder
cd ~/domains/name/public_html/$folder/sites/default/
echo "enabling u7seven theme!"
drush en u7seven -y;
echo "disabling overlay!"
drush dis overlay -y;
echo "running all-folder script!"
/absolute-path-to/u7d7up /absolute-path-to/all-folder
```

Comment: also one more question, If i'd want to call the script from different server, i can still use `/absolute-path` right? How would i deal with ssh username/password in that case, and still use it within same script?

Comment: @Michael in such cases you can use something called public key based auth (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) with blank passphrase and acheive what you want; since it will bypass the interactive password prompting.

Comment: can you provide one example of such kind? Thanks!